# Differentiate crash reporting between debug and production builds

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm setting up Firebase Crashlytics for my Android app, and I would like the crash reports for the debug version to be separate from all other versions.

There are several copies of the auto-generated values.xml file (that is generated when the google-services plugin processes toe `google-services.json` file) located in the different retrospective buildType folders. One of the strings contained in the files is:
    `<string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">{API-KEY}</string>`

The API key is the same for each buildType, so I'm thinking if I can just create a new API key for the debug version, it'll solve the problem but how to do this? Or is there another way (that doesn't involve changing the applicationId as I can't do this)?

I've searched the android docs, looked up other articles and looked through other SO answers but no luck.

Any help welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot differentiate the crash as per the build type (debug version).

You have to create a new project in the firebase with same app details (package name).

Get the API key for the project and then replace that key in your manifest file and **DONE**.

You just have to replace the key when you change your build Type.